How to stop Word from adding shadow to shapes by default?
Whenever I add a shape, Word automatically adds a shadow effect to the shape. I then have to manually turn off the shadow.
How do I stop this behavior?

Microsoft Word has templates to define standard document behavior.

Open a template, or create a new one.
In the template, Format > Picture Effects > Shadow, set the effect as desired.
There are other settings for drop shadow on text, too.
Save the template.
Make that the default template.

There can be multiple templates, which can be selected for different document types.

"create a new one" == create a new document, save it as a template later, isn't it?
